# How to search file text in subfolders using node.js

Tags: node.js, subdirectory

I have written code, which is supposed to search in all files with a certain file extension for a text.

For example:

`search.js txt alex` should look in all files for the string "alex" and return the full file name.

My problem is that it doesn't search in subdirectories.

How can I include subdirectories in the search?

My code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const dirPath = path.resolve(__dirname);
let filesList;
if (process.argv.length < 3) {
console.log('USAGE: node ' + ' search' + ' [EXT]' + ' [TEXT]');
process.exit(1);
}
fs.readdir(dirPath, function(err, files){
 filesList = files.filter(function(e){
  return path.extname(e).toLowerCase() === ('.'+process.argv[2])
 });
 filesList.map(d => {
  fs.readFile(d, function(err, cont) {
 if (err)
 throw err;
  if(cont.indexOf(process.argv[3])>-1){
  console.log(__dirname+'\\'+d);
    } else{
  console.log('No file was found')
  }
  });
   })
 });
```

Comment: I suggested updating your question title to: "How to search file text in subfolders using node.js"

Comment: You need to define a function that lists all items in a directory. If file type is what you're looking for, search. If item type is a directory, recursively call the same function with that directory. Otherwise, continue.

Comment: thanks but it not help me... :\

Comment: you can please edit my code and fix it for me? for who understanding i dont think is some one hard.... i try all the day, post it in every facebook groups that i know.... and nothing.. :\

Comment: @AlexBliznichenko "fix it for me" won't get you anywhere here but down voted answers, bud. There was a suggestion in this comment thread, did you try it?

Comment: i try yes.. but it not help.. i must to do that until Tuesday :\